# Ctrl+Shift+Del (clearing Browser cache) vs Session Expiry

Tags: session, caching, browser

Lets say session for an application is opened and its session expiry time is 15 min.

Scenarios:

- Leaving the application for 15 min and doing some action after that - leading to Login Page.
- In other way I am removing the Browser cookies by using (Ctrl+Shift+Del) and trying to navigate in the application - leading to Login Page.

The Question is: Will both of the above cases were one and the same or will there be any difference in the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The first scenario is based on a cookie expiring while the second one will have the cookie removed.

If you are guaranteed the refresh for the first case is made after the cookie expired, then the client behaviour will be the same (login page) although the internal workings will be different (check the cookie exists vs check its expiry date)

If you can't guarantee the operation will happen after the cookie expiry, then you won't get the same outcome.

Depending on what you do on the server, you might end up with multiple sessions for the same user in the second case, because the server doesn't know the user has deleted the cookie (there are mechanisms to compensate for this though).